# Using AJAX from another page to manipulate a database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am building a warranty product website as a side project for a small business I work at (We deal with batteries for cars, heavy equipment...). There is a lot going on here.

Basically, when an item gets returned for a warranty inspection the user can input the customer's information and the product information for it to be tracked and managed. I began with making a database in PHP (It is only one table and not fully normalized since it really does not need to be unless there is expansion later on) with only one table that manages transactions.

Each transaction when submitted defaults to ACTIVE status meaning it can be manipulated (Deleted, resolved, or to add a comment) via buttons in the table. To be able to do this I have been using AJAX to be able to use buttons in a table and change the Status to DELETED or RESOLVED. [image: ALL inspections table]

Now, there are four pages of tables (Like ALL, ACTIVE, DELETED, and RESOLVED) and each ran a very similar code (While loop that displayed the table) with the expectation of the SQL statement. For example the ALL inspections table has nowhere clause in the SQL statement, while the ACTIVE Inspections table would have a where Status = "ACTIVE", as so on for resolved and deleted. Since displaying the data seemed repetitive to have a while loop, I decided to make one table.php page with a function call GetTableData and on each page (ACTIVE, ALL, DELETED...) I would include the PHP file, and then call and pass through the SQL statement, like so...

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Battery Wholesale Inspection Database</title>
</head>
<?php include 'headernNavbar.html'; include 'Actions/connection.php'; include 'Actions/table.php'?>
<body>
        <h1 id="title">Active Inspection Database</h1>

</body>
</html>

<?php 

$sql = "SELECT TransactionID, CustomerName, PhoneNumber, ReceivedDate, Item, DATE_FORMAT(ManufactureDate, '%m-%y') as Age , InitalVoltage, InitalCCA, Comments, WarrStatus FROM inspection.product WHERE product.WarrStatus = 'ACTIVE'  ORDER BY ReceivedDate DESC";
GetTableData($sql, $conn);
?>
```

Here is what the table.php file looks like...

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<?php
include 'Actions/connection.php';

function GetTableData($sql, $conn){
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    echo "<table id='inspectTable' class='inspectTable'>";
    echo "<thead><tr>";
    echo "<th>Customer</th>";
    echo "<th>Phone</th>";
    echo "<th>Received</th>";
    echo "<th>Item</th>";
    echo "<th>Age</th>";
    echo "<th>Voltage</th>";
    echo "<th>CCA/AH</th>";
    echo "<th>Comments</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th>";
    echo "<th colspan=3 >Tools</th>";
    echo "</thead></tr>";

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row 
        echo "<tbody class='dbTable'>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $id= $row['TransactionID'];
            echo "
            <tr><td>" . $row['CustomerName'] ."</td>
            <td>" . $row['PhoneNumber'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['ReceivedDate'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Item'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['InitalVoltage'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['InitalCCA'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['Comments'] ."</td>
            <td>" . $row['WarrStatus'] ."</td>";


            if ($row['WarrStatus'] == 'ACTIVE'){
                echo "<td><button class='deleteRow' id='".$id."' >Delete</button></td>
                    <td><button class='updateRow' id='".$id."' >Update</button></td>
                    <td><button class='resolveRow' id='".$id."' >Resolve</button></td>";

            }
            else{
                    echo "<td><button class='deleteRow' id='".$id."' disabled >Delete</button></td>
                    <td><button class='updateRow' id='".$id."'disabled >Update</button></td>
                    <td><button class='resolveRow' id='".$id."'disabled>Resolve</button></td>";
            }

        }


        echo "</tbody>";
    } else {
            echo "Not Data Avaibable.";
    }
}
?>
<script>
$(".deleteRow").click(function()
{
    var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'Action/deleteAction.php',
        data:'id='+del_id,
        success: function(data)

        {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});

$(".resolveRow").click(function()
{
    var del_id = $(this).attr('id');2
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'resolveAction.php',
        data:'id='+del_id,
        success: function(data)

        {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
    </script>
</html>
```

So, as an example when the user is on the ACTIVE inspections page, and the list gets called it is displayed. When the user wants to delete an entery and clicked delete, the deleteAction.php should be called and changes the status from ACTIVE to DELETE. Here is the php for that...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>delete action</title>
</head>
<?php include 'connection.php'?>
<?php 
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "UPDATE inspection.product
 SET DeletedDate = now(), WarrStatus = 'DELETED'
 WHERE TransactionID = $id";

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

?>
</html>
```

***Now here is the problem I am facing. When a button (For example the delete button) is clicked nothing changes.*** Unlike when I first had the while loop (in the table.php) on each page with the AJAX js stuff it worked like a charm. I am just not sure if I am missing something. Here are the things I have tried:

1. Had each while loop and SQL statement in each PHP page with the AJAX
2. Created a separate js file and referenced that in the table.php, as well as each PHP page
3. Only had the AJAX js stuff in the other pages but still called the GetTableData

*I have also not accomplished the updating comment button as of yet*

Could anyone let a hand here? I would greatly appreciate it! If you see any other things I should do to improve I would also appreciate that. This is my first web project out of the first year!

EDIT:
I also forgot to include that reference to ajax in the table.php, it is there on my system, but I was playing around and forgot to add it in the post! This didn't fix the issue.

EDIT:
So after playing around with it, it does work when putting the ajax js in each php file, however it does not work when I have a separate js file and including that into each php file. Is there a different way to do this for it is a little cleaner?

Comment: You definitely want the ajax in 1 js file instead of copied in each php file. Try to cut down on repetition from the outset. Chances are you're simply not including the js file properly. You either have to link to it via a script tag in each page or call it from another js file if you already have one.

Comment: Check your browser console for any Javascript error

Comment: Thank you for the helpful hint! I did not know you could do this!

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli

Comment: Thank you @ADyson, I know I have this problem. This is one of the tasks I have to complete. I am just trying to get the system up and running first!

Comment: Why? If you know it's a problem, then write the queries correctly the first time...it's not really any more difficult. Then you won't have to come back and re-write them all and then re-test all of it too (after you've already tested it once to ensure it's "working".). What a waste of time, writing large parts of your code twice.